# Error in Insert to varbinary(max) String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been terminated

Tags: sql-server, bulkinsert, varbinarymax

I have table with definition:

[image]

I have image files near 80kb. When I am trying insert data to table Usluga like this:

```
INSERT [dbo].[Usluga] (Nazvanie, Cena_za_poseshenie, Image)
SELECT N'Персональный тренинг', 50, ThumbnailPhoto.*
FROM OPENROWSET 
   (BULK 'MyFilePathToImage.jpg', SINGLE_BLOB) ThumbnailPhoto
go
INSERT [dbo].[Usluga] (Nazvanie, Cena_za_poseshenie, Image)
SELECT N'Бокс', 90, ThumbnailPhoto.*
FROM OPENROWSET 
  (BULK  'MyFilePathToImage.jpg', SINGLE_BLOB) ThumbnailPhoto
go
```

I give error

> String or binary data would be truncated.
>   The statement has been terminated.

But varbinary(max) allows save data from 0 through 2^31-1 (2,147,483,647) bytes.
How do I fix this?

Comment: Does that exact piece of code fail? The string or binary data truncation is annoyingly vague about which item is actually going to be truncated, so I would guess it is more likely that you are trying to insert a string longer than 20 characters into `Nazvanie`.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I am stupid! Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you're looking at the wrong column. Try resizing your `nvarchar(20)` column so it can accept more than 20 characters.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting similar error when trying to insert a image file as a blob to
SQL Server database, it would throw "RIGHT TRUNCATION" error.

I solved my problem by changing the blob column data type from `VARBINARY(MAX)` to
`IMAGE`. The `varbinary(max)` datatype was supposed to replace the `image` datatype in newer SQL Server instances, my instance was SQL Server 2012. If using the `Image` data type works for you, then just keep in mind that the max size for this type is 2 GB.